# How to deploy Docker file to real machine

Tags: deployment, docker, development-environment, production-environment, server

**Background:** I am using Docker to build my development environment (web-app, nginx, gunicorn, postgress required to mention few). I want my development environment to match production environment. I am now using debian 7 as the base distro, but the question is not Debian related. I do not want docker on the actual production (security updates, monitoring, logging to mention few, but thats different question why not), but i want to use 'real' Debian 7 as the production environment.

**Question:**  Is there way to run the commands building the docker-image as local commands, eg like: `docker deploy_to_host <Dockerfile>` that would run the `RUN` instructions as root commands etc. That is similar affect as i would have host root command open and copy-paste the commands manually.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you are using the wrong set of tools, so my answer isn't about Docker and this is why:

If you are to deploy on the production environment without Docker and wish to have some kind of automatic process to prepare the machine and deploy the app then you are looking for tools such as:

- [Chef](https://www.getchef.com/chef/)
- [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/)
- [SaltStack](http://www.saltstack.com/)
- [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/home)
- or just shell scripts

Once you are decided on how to deploy to production you can then look at your options for your development environment.

Since you are not using Docker in production, there is little interest in using it on your development environment. I would then consider using [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) to define one (or more) virtual machines and have Vagrant prepare those VM with the tool you chose for the production env. (Chef, Puppet, SaltStack, Ansible or shell scripts). See [Vagrant provisioning](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/index.html).

That will have the advantage of testing your deployment solution as well as testing your app on the development environment and build up the confidence that all this will work as expected when deploying to prod.

Answer (score 0):

You can use remote docker API which covered [here](https://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.15/)
See section `2.3 Misc` and command `POST /build`. In few words, you can post tar-file which contains `Dockerfile` and its root to docker daemon to build it on remote machine.

**UPD**: Answer is not actual 'cause of my inattention.

Comment: Sorry my question is maybe badly formatted. I am not trying to build Docker file on remote machine, but rather to get the host Debian to run all the same commands that the docker would run when building the image.

Comment: Oh, my fault. Sorry my inattention.